# Is "tal cosas" accepted as standard Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, concordancia-gramatical

I came across the phrase "tal cosas" the other day and may have even used it in conversation myself, but at some point I got to wondering if I should be using "tales cosas" instead.  So, I did a search for these two phrases with Google's Ngram Viewer:

[image]

and, as you can see, very few instances of "tal cosas" seem to be in existence, but it appears that the phrase is being used and even found in books that appear to be written by native Spanish speakers.  Some examples:

> **"No son evangélicos quienes tal cosas hacen, ..."**
>   *"Those who do such things are not evangelical, ..."*
>   [*— Pluralismo religioso en España,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=a8TYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tal+cosas%22&dq=%22tal+cosas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nfXx2dLeAhWpHzQIHQ24DBc4UBDoAQgpMAA) de José Luis Coêlho Pires, ‎Julián García Hernando, p. 429 (1992)
>
> "**... y ellos respondieron: 'aquí los jóvenes hacen tal y tal cosas'" [...]**
>   *"... and they responded:'young people do such and such here'" [...]*
>   [*— Identidades en transformación: juventud indígena, migración y experiencia transnacional en Cañar, Ecuador,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TO40Od5JSygC&q=%22tal+cosas%22&dq=%22tal+cosas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nfXx2dLeAhWpHzQIHQ24DBc4UBDoAQg9MAM) de Jorge Daniel Vásquez Arreaga, p. 98 (2014)
>
> **"... quienes tal cosas afirman se quedan sólo en el prólogo de 'El reino de este mundo,' ..."**
>   *"... those who affirm such things remain only in the prologue of* The Kingdom of this World *..."*
>   [*— Los espejismos de las primeras hierbas,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lERIAAAAYAAJ&q=%22tal+cosas%22&dq=%22tal+cosas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI-dCt3dLeAhWEGDQIHXROD1I4eBDoAQhbMAg) de Orlando González Moreno, p. 265 (1996)

I've even seen instances of "tal cosas" in recent online news articles as well:

> **"... si publicitas tal cosas, ..."**
>   *"... if you advertise such things, ..."*
>   — ["La carta de una fan de Aitana, que refleja su decepción con la artista, se convierte en viral",](https://us.hola.com/actualidad/20181102132342/ot-aitana-ocana-carta-fan/) *Hola*
>
> **"... pasan tal cosas ..."**
>   *"... such things happen ...*"
>   — ["Simeone: 'En todos los equipos importantes hay lesiones'",](https://www.marca.com/futbol/atletico/2018/11/09/5be582bf46163f58868b465a.html) *MARCA.com*
>
> "**Quien sea capaz de decir tal cosas es que la tiene de cemento armado.**"
>   *"Whoever is able to say such things is the person who has reinforced concrete."*
>   — ["Guedes es de Jorge Mendes, por si a alguno se le ha olvidado en Valencia",](http://www.deportevalenciano.com/2018/08/28/guedes-jorge-mendes-le-olvidado-valencia) *Deporte Valenciano*

but not in any *El País* articles.  Then again, I haven't seen any "tales cosas" in any *El País* articles either.

Be that as it may, I am assuming that "tales cosas" is considered acceptable, but I'm not so sure about "tal cosas" (especially when a search of the CORDE returned nothing for this phrase, but did have some results for "tales cosas").  The relatively few instances of "tal cosas" I have found have made me think that it isn't considered standard Spanish.  I've even taken a look at [these pages](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi), but a quick glance tells me that neither addresses the question I've posed here.

Can anyone clear this up for me?  If you can cite some sources, even better.

---

¿Se acepta "tal cosas" como español estándar?

Me encontré con la frase “tal cosas” el otro día y es posible que la usé en una conversación yo misma, pero en algún momento, me puse a pensar si debería usar “tales cosas” en lugar de eso.  Así que, hice una búsqueda estas dos frases con el Ngram Viewer de Google:

[Véanse arriba en la sección escrita en inglés.]

y, como puedes ver, muy pocas instancias de “tal cosas” parecen existir, pero parece que la frase se utiliza y se encuentra incluso en libros que parecen estar escritos por hispanohablantes nativos.  Algunos ejemplos:

[Véanse arriba en la sección escrita en inglés.]

También, incluso he visto instancias de “tal cosas” en noticias recientes en la red.

[Véanse arriba en la sección escrita en inglés.]

pero, no las vi las frases “tal cosas” ni siquiera “tales cosas” en artículos de *El País.*

Sea como fuere, estoy asumiendo que “tales cosas” se considera aceptable, pero no estoy tan segura de “tal cosas” (especialmente cuando una búsqueda de CORDE no resultó en nada para esta frase, pero algunos resultados aparecieron por “tales cosas”.  Los relativamente pocos casos de “tal cosas” que he encontrado me han hecho pensar que no se acepta como correcto según las reglas de gramática en español.  Incluso he echado un vistazo a estas páginas [véanse el enlace arriba en la parte inglés], pero una mirada rápida me dice que ninguno de los dos aborda la pregunta que he planteado aquí.

¿Puede alguien aclararme esto?  Si puedes citar algunas fuentes, aún mejor.

Answer (score 5):

**Tal cosas** is grammatically wrong. The quoted resources are typos or simply mistakes.

According to the D.R.A.E

**[tal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Yy91lUI)**

> Del lat. talis.
>
> **Neutro** tal.
>
> 1. **adj. dem**. Ese, dicho o que se acaba de mencionar. Profirió insultos y amenazas, y tal comportamiento provocó su inmediata expulsión. U.
>      raramente con artículo antepuesto. Hicieron el pedido de las armas y
>      esperaron con paciencia las tales armas.
> 2. **adj. dem**. De estas o esas características o clase. U. m. pospuesto. Las temibles tormentas de octubre arrasaron la isla. Nadie se esperaba
>      tormentas tales.

I've highlighted **adj.dem**: adjetivo demostrativo.

As an **adjective** in Spanish, it must match gender and number (singular or plural) of the name that it accompanies. **Tal** is **neutro**, so it does not have different forms for gender. But it does have a plural form: **tales**. So if you use **tal** to modify the name **cosas** (plural), the correct form is **tales.**

I've come with this example that may help you. The word **esa** is another adjetivo demostrativo, and you can replace "tal" by it in multiple contexts, remembering that "esa" is not "neutro", it must match the gender too.
**Esa cosas** sounds wrong to a native speaker, noun and adjective does not match in number. Just the same thing occurs with "tal".

---

**Tal cosas** es incorrecto gramaticalmente. Los textos citados son erratas o simplemente errores.

De acuerdo con el D.R.A.E

**[tal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Yy91lUI)**

> Del lat. talis.
>
> **Neutro** tal.
>
> 1. **adj. dem**. Ese, dicho o que se acaba de mencionar. Profirió insultos y amenazas, y tal comportamiento provocó su inmediata expulsión. U.
>      raramente con artículo antepuesto. Hicieron el pedido de las armas y
>      esperaron con paciencia las tales armas.
> 2. **adj. dem**. De estas o esas características o clase. U. m. pospuesto. Las temibles tormentas de octubre arrasaron la isla. Nadie se esperaba
>      tormentas tales.

He resaltado **adj.dem**: adjetivo demostrativo.

Como **adjetivo**, en español debe coincidir en género y número (singular o plural) con el nombre que acompaña. **Tal** es **neutro**, no tiene diferentes formas dependiendo del género. Pero sí tiene forma plural: **tales**. Por tanto si usas **tal** como modificador del nombre **cosas** (plural), la forma correcta es **tales**

Se me ha ocurrido otro ejemplo que quizás te ayude. La palabra **esa** es un adjetivo demostrativo, y se puede reemplazar "tal" por ella en muchos contextos, teniendo en cuenta que "esa" no es neutra, debe coincidir en género también. **Esa cosas** suena erroneo para un hispanohablante, el nombre y el adjetivo no concuerdan en número. Justo pasa lo mismo con "tal".

Comment: Ojo: que algo sea *neutro* es diferente a que sea *invariable en cuanto a género*.  Hay pocos adjetivos que disponen de una forma neutra que se diferencia de la masculina (los demostrativos, básicamente) pero lo curioso es que el neutro no tiene plural y ello (ja) es posible porque el neutro verdadero nunca refiere a sustantivos (que siempre tienen género)

Comment: @guifa Me he perdido un poco. Yo quería indicar que "tal" como adjetivo tiene una única forma en singular, ni masculina ni femenina, que se emplea para ambos generos. Creo que a eso se refiere el D.R.A.E con lo de neutro en este caso. No he entendido bien cómo mejorar mi respuesta incorporando algo de lo que comentas. Este neutro tiene plural. No sé a qué te refieres con neutro verdadero que no se refiere a sustantivos. En este caso "tal" acompaña a un nombre y en los ejemplos de arriba se "pluraliza".

Comment: @guifa Ojo, que no pretendía ser borde. Que aquí no se lee bien el tono.

Comment: @guifa  Entiendo bien lo que explicaste en tu comentario.  No sé si el DRAE hace la distinción entre _neutro_ y _invariable en cuanto a género._  Veo mucho la abreviación [_inv_](http://www.wordreference.com/es/abbreviations-spanish.aspx?dict=enes) en WordReference y lo encuentro útil, pero los ejemplos que encuentro más fácilmente se refieren a colores (o, más generalmente, algunas palabras que pueden ser ambas un sustantivo o un adjetivo, pero no cambian su forma).

Comment: [Este artículo](https://www.thoughtco.com/invariable-adjectives-3079101) es un ejemplo.  Otros ejemplos incluyen estos, pero estos son un poco diferentes: _[arco iris,](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=rainbow) [rompehielos,](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=ice-breaker) [dabuten,](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=dabuten) [maquis,](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=maquis) …_

Comment: Sea como fuere, más allá de _invariable_ o aún _neutro_, creo que _no tiene ninguna flexión para género_ podría ser incluso mejor.  Dicho esto, no pude evitar notar que la entrada para "tal" en el DRAE (por debajo del latín) incluye "Neutro tal."  En mi mente, ningún adjetivo tiene género; simplemente tienen flexión para corresponder con un sustantivo que lo tiene.

Comment: Quiero añadir una última cosa.  WordReference menciona que palabras como _tal, amable, constante_ y otras, se llaman _adjetivos de una sola terminación._  (Para ver esto, [busca la palabra _tal_](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tal) en WordReference y pasa el ratón sobre _adj mf_.)  Voy a publicar una respuesta y en ella, lo explicaré un poco más.

Comment: @LisaBeck He mirado este último enlace que indicas y en el tip que aparece al pasar el ratón, se indica claramente que esos adjetivos tienen plural, que era tu pregunta original.

Comment: @rubioric tu comentario no me resultó nada borde, no te preocupes.  Es solo una cuestión pequeña de terminología, pero aparte de ello no hay nada malo en tu análisis.  Para sustantivos, hay cinco «géneros»: masculino (libro), femenino (revista), común (periodista), epiceno masculino (lince), epiceno femenino (bellena).  El común es invariable en cuanto a género (se dice el periodista, la periodista pero sí cambian de género), los epicenos no cambian de género aunque el referente sea masculino o femenino (siempre se dice la ballena, sea macho o hembra).

Comment: Para los adjetivos, hay cinco formas (masculino singular, femenino singular, masculino plural, femenino plural y neutro).  Lo que pasa es que la forma del neutro es idéntica al masculino (pero se usa cuando se describe cualquier cosa que no sea un sustantivo, por ejemplo, acciones *comer y beber es divertido* —fíjate el uso del singular tanto en adjetivo como en verbo).  Para describir los adjetivos, ya que todos pueden existir en esas cinco «formas» (sean distintas o no), decimos que son invariables cuando no cambian de forma, que pueden ser invariables en cuanto a género o a número.

Comment: @guifa Me apunto todas esas cosas. Siendo de ciencias, no llegué a profundizar tanto en esos aspectos. Gracias! :-)

Comment: Debo añadir que en el caso de *tal y tal cosas*, existe un pluralismo basado en el hecho que se discuten multiples *cosas* singulares. Esto causa que *tal cosas* se encuentre en una frase que no es completa, porque sería *tal y tal cosas*.

Comment: @guifa Me gustan mucho los detalles de tus comentarios.  De hecho, si podrías incluirlos en una respuesta que aborda de alguna manera la pregunta original, sería claramente merecedor de la marca verde.  Te daré tiempo para considerarlo.  Mientras tanto, muchas gracias por tus comentarios.  Son detallados, expresados claramente, y edificantes.

Comment: @psosuna - Gracias por señalar el caso especial *tal y tal*.  Me imagino que *tal y tal* es diferente que *tal*, en su acepción y su gramática.  (En inglés sería "such and so.")

Comment: @aparente001 Supongamos el ejemplo, *Es un horror cuando viene ese hombre a mi puerta a contarme tal y tal cosas, que no logro sacarlo de aquí. Es que habla demasiado.* -> En este caso correspondiría con la frase en inglés que sería *thing after thing*, o por igual *one thing after another*. Tiene un contraste muy marcado a comparación de la alternativa que sería *tales cosas*, y sustituyendo nos resulta la traducción *such things*

Answer (score 0):

I am not trying to diminish any of the efforts that have already been made in trying to answer this question.  In fact, at the very least, I was simply hoping that a native speaker of Spanish could definitively tell me that "tal cosas" is or is not a correct use of Spanish.  RubioRic, who has already done that, may, in fact, get the green check mark for his efforts, but I'll give others ample time to attempt an answer to my question before awarding the green check mark.

Having said that, I came across something today that helped me understand this little word "tal" a little better, and if reading this page helped me, I'm guessing it can help others as well.  I'll regurgitate information from this page in a way that I found useful and then end this answer with a link to the full article so you can read it in its entirety if you think that would be more useful or you just want to sate your curiosity.  With that, I'll begin.

The first thing I want to mention is that the word "tal" is, at its core, just an adjective.  It's a special kind of adjective, but it's still an adjective, so all the rules about Spanish adjectives you may have already learned apply to the word "tal."

Like I said, however, "tal" is a special kind of adjective.  It is what some call an "indefinite adjective" and falls into the same category as the following:

[image]
*Right click and open in a new tab if you have difficulty seeing the image above.  Also, for the record, I realize that some of the words in the chart above can be more than just "indefinite adjectives," but for the sake of simplicity and focus, this answer and the chart above do not address other parts of speech the words above can also be.*

And just as certain regular adjectives don't [**change form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) to match gender, neither do some of the indefinite adjectives.  "Tal" is one of these.  The chart above lays out which indefinite adjectives fully inflect, which ones only have partial inflection, and which ones don't inflect at all.

You'll find [**this slide**](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fslideplayer.es%2Fslide%2F10870239%2F39%2Fimages%2F6%2FLos%2Badjetivos%2Bconcuerdan%2Ben%2Bg%25C3%25A9nero%2By%2Bn%25C3%25BAmero%2Bcon%2Blos%2Bsustantivos%2Ba%2Blos%2Bque%2Bacompa%25C3%25B1an..jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fslideplayer.es%2Fslide%2F10870239%2F&docid=FXEFW5cMzjhIHM&tbnid=XHZbuzdo-6jKDM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiVj4KNxtXeAhUJj1QKHWP5DLcQMwhBKAEwAQ..i&w=960&h=720&bih=833&biw=1726&q=%22adjetivos%20de%20una%20sola%20terminaci%C3%B3n%22&ved=0ahUKEwiVj4KNxtXeAhUJj1QKHWP5DLcQMwhBKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8) in this presentation here:

[**EL ADJETIVO CALIFICATIVO**](https://slideplayer.es/slide/10870239/)

It may help you further.  And if you'd like the link to the page that helped me write this answer, you'll find it below:

### [**Indefinite Adjectives**](https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/adjectives/indefinite-adjectives/)

Comment: It's not about gender here, but about number. Because the substantive "cosas" is plural, so must be the adjective, and we should say "tales cosas". 
BTW, I'm native speaker of Spanish (Argentina) , and "tal cosas" sounds to me definitely wrong.